# Can't get xs:element with attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have XML elements with and without attributes

```
<xs:element name='element0'>
 <xs:complexType name='internationalShoeSize'>
  <xs:annotation>
   <xs:documentation>Data ...</xs:documentation>
 </xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
   <xs:extension base='xs:string'>
     <xs:attribute name='attribute0' type='xs:string' />
   </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name='element1'>
 <xs:complexType name='internationalShoeSize'>
  <xs:annotation>
   <xs:documentation>Data1 ...</xs:documentation>
 </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

When I get the elements in a DataTable, only get the elements without attributes.

```
foreach(DataColum colum in table.colums)
{
  ....
}
```

This foreach only get the elements without attributes: the `element1`.
How can I get all the elements, with and without attributes?

Comment: How to do transform your XML into `DataTable` instance?

Comment: DataTable customerTable = dataSet.Tables["Customer"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to start with a better schema snippet, the one you've posted is mangled beyond use. I took yours and cleaned it up - in the process maybe deviated from your intentions; feel free to take my sample and used it to edit your question for better illustration.

`(Alternatively, if you have a sample XML, post that instead - it might be even easier to explain.)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="element0" type="internationalShoeSize"/>

    <xs:element name="element1" type="internationalShoeSize"/>

    <xs:complexType name="internationalShoeSize">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Data ...</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="attribute0" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Meanwhile, this is the equivalent data structure you would get (on .NET):

[image]

Your attribute is there...